# Delete messages that have any links

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a new project and I need to have a link filter, were pretty much anyone that doesn't have the permission `ADMINISTRATOR` can't send links, if they do, the bot will automatically delete the message.

My code:

```js
client.on('message', message =>{
    if (message.content.includes(`http://`)) {
        if (message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            return
        }
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send(`You are not allowed to send links ${message.author}`))
    }

})
```

The code doesn't error, but whenever someone send's a link or just sends the text `http://` the bot doesn't do anything.

Comment: Most links are `https://`. Have you tried `console.log` inside your function to see what paths the code takes?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes I have, and nothing shows up in the logs

Comment: Using discord v12 or 13 also please post you client `Intents`

Comment: @Gh0st I'm on version 17.1.0

Comment: That looks like a node version (as there is no Discord v17 yet) please run this command in terminal `npm view discord.js version`

Comment: If this comes back as 13.x.x the change your `client.on(‘message’` to `client.on(‘messageCreate’`. If your version is 12.x.x then don’t change it.

Comment: Yes I'm on v13. I will try that

Answer (score 3):

Best solution will be this, if this fails then you are missing client intents

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require(‘discord.js’)
// other constants
const client = new Client({
    intents: [/*intent flags here*/]
// intent flags are enabled by putting Intents.FLAGS.IntentNameHere, Intents.FLAGS.NextIntentNameHere. Etc
// example: intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
// or use intents: 131071 for all intents

    })
// other code
client.on(‘messageCreate’, async message => {
    if (/(https?)/gi.test(message.content)) {
        if (message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            return
        } else {
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send(`You are not allowed to send links ${message.author}`)
        }
    }
})
// rest of code
```

UPDATE intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071

Comment: It's not working, what can I do?

Comment: @JustRedX update my answer you can find intent flags [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) or just use `32767` as I mentioned.

Comment: The `client.on` is missing a comma after `'messageCreate'` which may be spawning the issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("http://discord.gg")) { //upper or lower cases included
   message.delete(); //delete the message 
   message.channel.send(`No links here, ${user}`) //send message after deletion
}
```

Comment: this would just look for links to discord servers, and it would fail most of the time since discord uses `https`, not `http`. This also doesn't solve the problem of the OP forgetting intents or calling for the wrong event based on their discordjs version.

Comment: The link provide only for example links, still the OP tell what link he/she wanted to add,

Comment: OP question was to block all links being posted, using this method would only block links included in the `includes` but allowing all others. Using a RegEx to filter it (even in your code example) would be a better solution. `if (/(?:https?:\/)?discord(?:app.com\/invite|.gg)/gi.test(message.content))` should you ever want it.